# Flows that are multiples of vorticity are steady flows proof

Tags: vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

Define the flow $\vec{u}(\vec{x},t)=\alpha(\vec{x},t)\vec{\omega}(\vec{x},t)$ where $\alpha(\vec{x},t)$ is some scalar field. I am trying to show that
$$
\frac{\partial\vec{u}}{\partial t}=\vec{0}.
$$
From the incompressible vorticity equation (with zero body force) I know that
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial\vec{\omega}}{\partial t} & = \nabla\times(\vec{u}\times\vec{\omega})\\
& = \nabla\times(\alpha\vec{\omega}\times\vec{\omega})=\vec{0},
\end{split}
$$
so by the product rule I know also that
$$
\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial t}\vec{\omega},
$$
and here I am stuck.

Comment: Do you mean vorticity instead of viscosity?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I do, thanks for spotting that. I've just changed it.

Comment: Your first step isn't quite right. You need to use the product rule.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Product rule tells me $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial (\alpha\omega_i)}{\partial t}=\alpha \frac{\partial (\omega_i)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial (\alpha)}{\partial t}\omega_i=\frac{\partial (\alpha)}{\partial t}\omega_i$ since  $\frac{\partial (\omega_i)}{\partial t}=0$. What isn't correct here?

Comment: You're right. I made a couple of stupid comments which I deleted. The task is to show $\partial_t \alpha = 0$ or $\vec{\omega} = 0$. The latter implies the flow is $\vec{0}$, in which case the result obviously follows. Hence we must show $\partial_t \alpha = 0$. I'm a bit at a loss. Perhaps try taking the curl and time derivative of $\vec{u}$ and then substituting into the vorticity equation?